# Bluetooth module with external antenna?

Tags: bluetooth

I was referred here from the Raspberry Pi stack exchange.  I'm looking for a bluetooth module that can use an external SMA antenna, that I can interface with a raspberry pi.  I'm very new to raspberry pi, and fairly inexperienced in Bluetooth too, so any advice would be greatly appreciated. I've tried searching to find these answers to no avail, but if they've already been answered elsewhere, I'd be happy to read that thread too.

Ok, so I need a module that can do what I think is the bare minimum capabilities. All it needs to do is read the names of discoverable devices, and their RSS. That's it. Doesn't need to interpret any other type of data, doesn't need to be able to transmit data, doesn't even need to be able to pair.

And, again, it needs to be able to use an external SMA antenna.

It seems like most of the chips that are bluetooth with external antennas seem to have been discontinued.

1) Do you know of currently-sold modules that could accomplish these goals?

2) WiFi modules seem to often have external antennas... could I detect bluetooth devices and RSS with a Wifi module? I know they read similar frequencies, but I imagine they are somehow different and this wouldn't work

3) Would this piece of hardware work? It has an external antenna, but it seems like it's already built to interpret audio signals and deliver them as output. Not sure how I'd go about just getting the simple RSS and not all the other jazz. https://www.tinyosshop.com/index.php?route=product/product&path=65_110&product_id=1003